# Conditional Probability Problem with Dependent Events

Tags: probability

Let's suppose there is a countdown timer with $X$ seconds remaining, and that there are three groups of different objects, then let's call the number of objects in each group $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Then suppose that for every second that ticks down on the timer, one object is randomly removed from one of the three piles. So if we started with $X = 200$, $A = 100$, $B = 100$, and $C = 100$; then at $X = 190$ we could have $A = 98$, $B = 97$, and $C = 95$ for example.

Then what is the probability that one of $A$, $B$, or $C$ reaches $0$ before $X$ reaches $0$ if $A = 131$, $B = 133$, $C = 168$, and $X = 140$? Further, how can we generalize this problem to find the probability that one of $A$, $B$, or $C$ reaches $0$ before $X$ reaches $0$ with any $A$, $B$, $C$, and $X$ as long as one of $A$, $B$, and $C$ is strictly less than $X$ (otherwise the probability would be zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining

$$(a+b+c)^{10}$$
[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E10) gives this as the hefty:

$$a^{10} + 10 a^9 b + 10 a^9 c + 45 a^8 b^2 + 90 a^8 b c + 45 a^8 c^2 + 120 a^7 b^3 + 360 a^7 b^2 c + 360 a^7 b c^2 + 120 a^7 c^3 + 210 a^6 b^4 + 840 a^6 b^3 c + 1260 a^6 b^2 c^2 + 840 a^6 b c^3 + 210 a^6 c^4 + 252 a^5 b^5 + 1260 a^5 b^4 c + 2520 a^5 b^3 c^2 + 2520 a^5 b^2 c^3 + 1260 a^5 b c^4 + 252 a^5 c^5 + 210 a^4 b^6 + 1260 a^4 b^5 c + 3150 a^4 b^4 c^2 + 4200 a^4 b^3 c^3 + 3150 a^4 b^2 c^4 + 1260 a^4 b c^5 + 210 a^4 c^6 + 120 a^3 b^7 + 840 a^3 b^6 c + 2520 a^3 b^5 c^2 + 4200 a^3 b^4 c^3 + 4200 a^3 b^3 c^4 + 2520 a^3 b^2 c^5 + 840 a^3 b c^6 + 120 a^3 c^7 + 45 a^2 b^8 + 360 a^2 b^7 c + 1260 a^2 b^6 c^2 + 2520 a^2 b^5 c^3 + 3150 a^2 b^4 c^4 + 2520 a^2 b^3 c^5 + 1260 a^2 b^2 c^6 + 360 a^2 b c^7 + 45 a^2 c^8 + 10 a b^9 + 90 a b^8 c + 360 a b^7 c^2 + 840 a b^6 c^3 + 1260 a b^5 c^4 + 1260 a b^4 c^5 + 840 a b^3 c^6 + 360 a b^2 c^7 + 90 a b c^8 + 10 a c^9 + b^{10} + 10 b^9 c + 45 b^8 c^2 + 120 b^7 c^3 + 210 b^6 c^4 + 252 b^5 c^5 + 210 b^4 c^6 + 120 b^3 c^7 + 45 b^2 c^8 + 10 b c^9 + c^{10}$$

This homogeneous polynomial can then be interpreted as the number of times each timer was called, so we are looking for coefficients of terms with at least one exponent $\ge5$, for example $90 a b c^8$ or $252 b^5 c^5$.

The total number of cases (i.e. the sum of the coefficients when $a=b=c=1$) is, obviously, $3^{10}=59049$.

So for example, the probability of calling 4A, 5B, 1C is $\frac{1260}{59049}\approx0.021338$.

How you get these beats me at the moment:)

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, however, I am not sure I quite understand this answer. I'm not sure which exponents or limits you are referring to and I don't understand where some of this math is coming from. I assumed that there would be a fairly straightforward mathematical solution to this problem and that some statistical formula would probably cover most of it. But now seeing the complexity of the solution with larger numbers, I would like to offer a rephrased version for simplicity's sake. If the values were $A = 5$, $B = 5$, $C = 5$, and $X = 10$, then how might one get a solution?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, that clears up a lot of my confusion. So in the case where $A = 5$, $B = 5$, $C = 5$, and $X = 10$, if you wanted to find the probability of one of $A$, $B$, and $C$ reaching $0$ **before** $X$, then would you expand $(a + b + c)^9$ instead? Then you could take the sum of coefficients on terms where the exponent on one of $A$, $B$, and $C$ is greater than or equal to $5$ and divide this number by $3^9$. I feel like there should be some way to do this with combinatorics as well, but how exactly eludes me. Anyway, is this logic correct or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: @BobSmith; yes, because $\lt X \equiv \le (X-1)$ over the integers.